# TypeError when using vscode-tomcat

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, visual-studio-code

An error sometimes occurs when using the Tomcat plugin for Visual Studio Code on an AWS Cloud9 instance, which runs as follows: `TypeError: Cannot set property 'readableListening' of undefined`.

Starting the server is impossible without disabling the plugin, reloading the window and re-enabling the plugin.

Does anyone know of a proper fix for this issue? It would be greatly appreciated.